# What's this thing called? A list of command words at the top of the window

Tags: windows

[image: notepad]

So, I wanted to make my own "this thing" but I don't know what it's called to google it

Comment: it's called a menu bar. If you don't know what it's called in English why don't just search for it in your native language and translate if necessary?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know it in any language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called the [menu bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-menus). It is not a separate control, it is part of the parent HWND and you set it with [`SetMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setmenu).

To make your own, [take at look](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cc-faq-iemenubar) at how Internet Explorer does it.